# AdMob interstitial in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I have used AdMob previously for displaying banner ads and that is working in this project.
Now I wont to display AdMob ad after the game is over.
This is game written in SpriteKit.

In my GameScene after the game is lost I do:

```
GameOverScene* gameOverScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.frame.size playerScore:_topPoints playerTime:elapsedTime];
SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:2.5];
[self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition:transition];
```

This is working fine.

In GameOverScene.m I have:

```
@interface GameOverScene ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) GADInterstitial *interstitial; // for Ads
@end

@implementation GameOverScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size playerScore:(NSUInteger)score playerTime:(CFTimeInterval)elapsedTime;
{
    self = [super initWithSize:size];

    if (self)
    {
        // code for hight score just text label, not important

        // for adds
        [self performSelector:@selector(showBanner) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) showBanner
{
    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    self.interstitial.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    // Requests test ads on simulators.
    request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];

    [self performSelector:@selector(showBanner1) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
}

- (void) showBanner1
{
    if ([self.interstitial isReady])
    {
        NSLog(@"EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");

        [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:(UIViewController *)self];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NO NO NO NO AD");
        [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
    }
}
```

This code is being executed, but I have following problem:

```
[self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:(UIViewController *)self];
```

Does runtime error:

```
-[GameOverScene presentViewController:animated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fee8b8ceb80
```

As far as I understand I think that there is some problem because `self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:` is expecting RootViewController but my GameOverScene is SKScene.

**QUESTION**
How to display AdMob interstitial in SKScene ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GameOverScene is not UIViewController. Do like this.

```
@interface AppDelegate 
{
    ViewController *viewController;
} 
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
```

In ViewController.m assign.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
     AppDelegate *app = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
     app.viewController = self;
}
```

//In any place

```
-(void)SetupAdmob  //call only first time
{
       mInterstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    mInterstitial_.adUnitID = ADMOB_FULL_SCREEM;
    [mInterstitial_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

    [self performSelector:@selector(showAdmobInterstitial) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
}

-(void)showAdmobInterstitial  //call this to show fullScreen ads
{
    AppDelegate *app = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])

    [mInterstitial_ presentFromRootViewController: app.viewController];

    mInterstitial_ = nil;

    mInterstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init]; //Cache new ads for next time
    mInterstitial_.adUnitID = ADMOB_FULL_SCREEM;
    [mInterstitial_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

}
```

Comment: thera are some errors with your code. Like, where do I put first part "@interface AppDelegate ...". Also this code in `ViewController.m` is giving me error "Use of undeclared identifier 'AppDelegate'"

Comment: I manage to use your code, but I need to do lot of changes. Your code is good, but you just didi copy/paste from your own project so you didi not copy/paste everything, but It is useful.

Comment: @WebOrCode I thought u r expert iPhone developer n not sent all code. Actually this AppDelegate class we learn't in first class of iPhone development :) Happy Coding.

Comment: It is better to put code that is working, out of the box, for other people also.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set

```
@import GoogleMobileAds;
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController <GADBannerViewDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate>
```

And also set

```
self.interstitial.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution easier and simpler in Swift:

```
let currentViewController:UIViewController=UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!

interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(currentViewController)
```